# -o in iptables is for specifying the interface for OUTPUT, FORWARD, and POSTROUTING Correct?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

Reading in detail about iptables / netfilter [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/iptables-add-rule/), when I read about the `-o` argument:

> "Indicates the interface through which the outgoing packets are sent
>   through the INPUT, FORWARD, and PREROUTING chain."

This seems to me to be wrong as they have written the same thing for the `-i` argument.

It seems to me it should instead be:

> "Indicates the interface through which the outgoing packets are sent
>   through the OUTPUT, FORWARD, and POSTROUTING chain."

correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep, man page debian;

```
   [!] -o, --out-interface name
          Name  of  an  interface via which a packet is going to be sent (for packets entering the FORWARD, OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains).  When the "!" argument is used before the
          interface name, the sense is inverted.  If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match.  If this  option  is  omitted,  any
          interface name will match.
```